# Conflict between jaad and javax sound

Tags: java, audio

I have a small utility class for obtaining the sample rate of a WAV file. The high-level code is below (full example is in the [sample project on GitHub](https://github.com/yschondorf/jaad-conflict-sample-project/tree/main) )

```
public static int getSampleRate(String audioFilePath) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File audioFile = new File(audioFilePath);
    
    try {
        AudioFileFormat audioFileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(audioFile);
        int sampleRate = (int) audioFileFormat.getFormat().getSampleRate();
        return sampleRate;
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException|IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly until I add Jaad dependency in pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tianscar.javasound</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaad</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

This causes Jaad to interfere somehow and the line -

```
AudioFileFormat audioFileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(audioFile);
```

results in an exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "net.sourceforge.jaad.aac.SampleRate.getFrequency()" because the return value of "net.sourceforge.jaad.aac.DecoderConfig.getSampleFrequency()" is null

```
at net.sourceforge.jaad.aac.Decoder.<init>(Decoder.java:77)
at net.sourceforge.jaad.aac.Decoder.create(Decoder.java:57)
at net.sourceforge.jaad.aac.Decoder.create(Decoder.java:51)
at net.sourceforge.jaad.spi.javasound.AACAudioFileReader.decodeAACAudio(AACAudioFileReader.java:50)
at net.sourceforge.jaad.spi.javasound.AACAudioFileReader.decodeAACAudioFileFormat(AACAudioFileReader.java:42)
at net.sourceforge.jaad.spi.javasound.AACAudioFileReader.getAudioFileFormat(AACAudioFileReader.java:173)
at net.sourceforge.jaad.spi.javasound.AACAudioFileReader.getAudioFileFormatAndClose(AACAudioFileReader.java:228)
at net.sourceforge.jaad.spi.javasound.AACAudioFileReader.getAudioFileFormat(AACAudioFileReader.java:242)
at java.desktop/javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(AudioSystem.java:976)
```

...

I included two tests in the [sample project on GitHub](https://github.com/yschondorf/jaad-conflict-sample-project/tree/main) :

- AacSampleRateExtractorTest - runs successfully and extracts the sample rate from an AAC file using Jaad
- AudioWavSampleTest - fails because of the problem I described above. This test can be made to work by removing the Jaad dependency from pom.xml.

I have not encountered any known compatibility problem between Jaad and Javax sound. Am I missing something? Is this a known bug of Jaad?
Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn’t really fix the problem, but it should serve as a workaround, at least for .wav files.

You can restrict Java Sound to using only Java SE-provided readers, then only if that fails, fall back to using the entire set of available providers, including jaad.

```
static AudioFileFormat getFormat(File file)
throws IOException,
       UnsupportedAudioFileException {

    ServiceLoader<AudioFileReader> readers = ServiceLoader.load(
        System.class.getModule().getLayer(), AudioFileReader.class);

    for (AudioFileReader reader : readers) {
        try {
            return reader.getAudioFileFormat(file);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            // Ignore
        }
    }

    return AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file);
}
```

ServiceLoader is the [java.util.ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) class.  AudioFileReader is the [javax.sound.sampled.spi.AudioFileReader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/spi/AudioFileReader.html) class.